# Prevent infinity loop when using MongoDB change stream with the Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo, changestream

I want to write api that reactive mongodb changes and update ConcurrentHashMap 
but my program get stock in infinity loop when i using MongoDatabase.Collection.watch()

Is there a possibility that it will run in the background and the program will continue?
or create multi watch collection?

Comment: Run the `watch` in its own thead? The `watch` will block if there are no changes to detect.

Comment: I thought it creates an infinity loop and then the other threads will be in starvation mode